# Problem using `cut` with `tail -f`

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to follow a log file and want to extract a field from it. I've tried

```
tail foo.txt | cut -f 5
```

and this works, but if I try to follow changes via

```
tail -f foo.txt | cut -f 5
```

nothing is printed, even when there are changes to the file.

Any suggestions or comments about why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BASH FAQ entry #9: "What is buffering? Or, why does my command line produce no output: tail -f logfile | grep 'foo bar' | awk ..."](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009)

Comment: Is there a way to force unbuffering with cut? Incidentally, I switched to using awk, and the buffering problem went away.

Comment: `unbuffer` will force unbuffering in almost any program.